# Using LINQ MIN() function with a JOIN

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to get the first order that has been placed by each customer based on a Timestamp.

Below is some pseudo code, that doesn't compile :

```
var minOrders = (from Orders in DataSet.Orders select Orders.OrderTimestamp).Min()
                 join Customers in DataSet.Customers on Orders.CustomerId equals Customers.CustomerId
                 select new
                 {
                    Customers.Name,
                    Orders.OrderAmount
                 });
```

Any pointers as to the correct LINQ structure would be great, Thanks.

Joe

Comment: Are you trying to get this for one specific customer, or the first order for *each* customer?

Comment: Hi Jon, for each.  I've edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the code you have written i supose you need the first order of each costumor

Your statement would be then

```
var minOrders = from customer in DataSet.Customers
                let order = (from o in DataSet.Orders
                             where o.CustomerId == customer.CustomerId
                             order by o.OrderTimestamp
                             select o).first()
                select new
                 {
                    customer.Name,
                    order.OrderAmount
                 });
```

Comment: Thanks for this Frederick - I was hoping to use MIN() for a slightly more elegant solution, I will use your answer as the basis though - Thanks

Comment: @Joe.Net Glad to help, i think with MIN it get a complexer. You could also look into sql methods in the namespace System.Data.Linq.SqlClient (might need to add a dll)

Comment: Thanks, out of interest, why would MIN be more complex?

Comment: @Joe.Net well i didn't find a good solution with min, if you find one you ca always tell me :)